# Can I stop this leak by just replacing this faucet?

Tags: water, leak, faucet

Outside of the house, there is a water leak from this faucet.  Looks like it runs between the house and the water shut off valve.  On the other side of the water shut off is some irrigation piping which I have off since it's old and broken.

It's dripping every few seconds.  Is this something where I can turn the water off and replace the leaking faucet myself or is this more involved?

Pics:  https://ibb.co/album/CJGmDC

Thank you

Comment: Please put your images in the post here. If the link dies the question becomes nearly useless.

Comment: Does the drip come from the spout (the threaded connection for a water hose), or does the drip come from around the shaft just below the handle?

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica from the spout

Answer (score 1):

There's a nut below the handle that you'll need to remove by turning it counterclockwise with an adjustable wench. Then turn the valve stem counter clockwise and remove it from the valve base. Replace the rubber washer at the bottom of the valve stem and then re assemble. Tighten up everything and you should be good to go....  and yes, you need to turn off the water before doing this. If you don' have a shutoff at your house, you can call your water department and have the water shutoff at the street or before your meter.

Comment: Thank you, will give that  go.